# Can you Recover a Wordpress User from a Backup

Tags: users, backup

so basically i deleted a wordpress user, and with that user, the settings, media and many pages were deleted. is there a way to restore only that user, because he has been inactive for about a year, and the last backup is about one year ago.

Comment: You could definitely do this manually if you have an SQL backup of your database. It would be quite a lot of manual work, but it's possible. You'd need direct access to your database and quite a lot of familiarity with SQL. I'm checking to see if users/posts are really get deleted or if they're still left in the database somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a test on Wordpress 5.4.2. I made a new user, and then made a post and a page from that user, then deleted the user and chose not to reassign content to another user.

I looked in the database and found that the data in wp_users for the user was completely deleted, but in wp_posts the content created by that user was still there but set to trashed.

So, you may find that you can recover the posts/pages from the trash, however if they've been deleted from the trash they might be gone permanently.

You can always recover data from backups manually, however it would be quite a manual process to find the data from the backup and re-inserting it into the database manually, or re-entering it through the WP dashboard.

For more help see if you have a database backup that you can look at in a text editor and search for your wp_posts table to see if you can find where that information is, and paste an example of it here.